# Why standard inputs are not mixed in linux?

Tags: c, linux, stdin, file-descriptor, descriptor

We know that each process has set three descriptors in advance:

`0 (stdin), 1 (stdout), 2 (stderr)`

Why `stdin` between different processes are not mixed ? After all, each process has the same descriptor equals to `0`.  Can anyone explain it ?

Comment: Why is the data on line 1 of main.cpp different from the data on line 1 of readme.doc?  After all, both lines are ID #1....   The concept of a "Namespace" is fundamental to any sort of lookup system, even shows up in programming language design where it is called "scope".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each process has its own set of file descriptors. File descriptor 0 of one process doesn't necessarily reference the same file handle as file descriptor 0 of another process.

Same goes for memory addresses. Because of memory virtualization, each process has its own address space. Different process can use the same address for different purposes.

Comment: Oh, yeah. After all 0 is only index in descriptor table `t` (per process). However, `t[0]` refers to table of file description.